# Vector Laplacian on Manifolds

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, surfaces

I'm trying to understand some basics of calculus on a surface (i.e. a 2-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$), without having much knowledge in differential geometry (so from an engineer's perspective). I am not able to get much about how the vector Laplacian on surfaces is defined. There was a [similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158594/definition-of-vectorial-laplace-beltrami-operator), but the answer there seems to be above my pay grade.

Let's say we have a (sufficiently smooth) surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and (sufficiently smooth) functions $u: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\vec{v}: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Then, from a lay-man's perspective, for the projection operator(which removes the normal component) $P = \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}^T$, the surface derivatives can be defined as

\begin{align}
\nabla_S u &= P\nabla u = \text{(say) } \left( \begin{array}{c} D_1u \\ D_2 u \\ D_3 u \\ \end{array}\right) \\
\nabla_S \cdot \vec{v} &= P\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = D_1v_1 + D_2v_2 + D_3v_3\\
\Delta_S u &= \nabla_S \cdot \nabla_S u = D_1D_1u + D_2D_2u + D_3 D_3u
\end{align}

There seem to be multiple definitions for the Laplacian of a vector field [Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry). Two specific ones are what I am trying to understand. The Bochner Laplaican, and the Hodge Laplacian (since those are the ones used in the context I need). There is also a third one [here (starting after equation 1.1, till equation 1.3)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05114.pdf) that has me a bit confused.

Can any of them be understood in a way similar to the surface gradient/surface divergence/Laplace beltrami of a scalar field written above? Is any of them simply a component wise Laplace-Beltrami operator?

\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{c} 
\Delta_S v_1 \\ \Delta_S v_2 \\ \Delta_S v_3 \\ \end{array}\right)?
\end{equation}

Another way to look at this is to ask if we can define a Vector Laplacian on a 2-manifold in 3-space without going in to the differential geometry formalism. i.e. using cartesian coordinates only.

Comment: The Bochner Laplacian takes as input a section of a vector bundle, for example you can define it for  vector fields for $k$-differential forms or, more generally, for tensor fields. The Hodge Laplacian takes as input a $k$-differential form (a particular case of tensor field). Before understanding these two operators, you should understand what  these two objects are.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain: Therein lies the problem. A subquestion can be whether it is necessary to understand those abstractions when one is working only in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual metric. When the whole point of going coordinate free need not be helpful.

Comment: I edited my post to make it clear what I am only talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard inner product. Take the example of the Laplace-Beltrami on scalar fields. If one were to go by differential geometry texts, one may believe that one needs to understand the abstractions to understand how the operator works. But there is a more direct way to understand the same when we restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the standard inner product. The question is whether a similar thing can be done for the surface Laplacian of a vector field too.

Comment: You can recover the  Christoffel symbols from your definition of covariant derivative. Once you have the Christoffel's you can define the operators locally. Defining $\nabla^*$ without a definition of tensor product could be tedious and overall can hide its  geometric  content. That's only an opinion.